# How can we send data from one application to other application in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, air

I've developed an android app(APP1) in Eclipse which is use to launch the games.
The games which I wanna launch are developed using AIR for Android (i.e ported to android from flash games) say (APP2)

I'm able to launch the game(APP2) from my android app(APP1), now when the game is over then I want to fetch the score from APP2(i.e from the game played) and send back to APP1

please help me to do this with an example and its explanation...
Which will be really very appreciated..
Thank you.

Comment: service or sqlite database

Comment: I believe this question is _way_ too general for SO. However, take a look at Native Extensions for AIR, that is certainly your biggest hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

Make your App2  as a library project for App1 
then you can access app2  activity from app1.

Answer (score -1):

Did you Check **startActivityForResult()?**

Using it You can start another activity and receive a result back.

Check the below link for details  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Comment: The question is how to send data from one APPLICATION to another, not between ACTIVITIES in the same application.

Comment: Ummm... 'Application' on Android is actually a bunch of activities, intents, providers and so on, packaged together in an apk (which is simply an 'android package'). There is no such thing as an 'application' to which you can talk to, so the answer was factually correct, although probably not what you're after.